# delayed_job not seeing environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, delayed-job

The Rails 4 application is deployed to the production server using Capistrano 3. The delayed jobs daemon starts. When a job is created, it does not recognize environment variables set in `/etc/profile` using `ENV` (returns nil). Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your `/etc/profile` file?

Comment: `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=value`. Note: They are set and are available in the Rails application. Just not when the `delayed_job` tries to access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved the environment variables from `/etc/profile` to `/etc/environment` and that seemed to have fixed the problem. Maybe that's the way I was supposed to do it in the first place...I'm not a Linux expert.